# Generation of random numbers - Math.random()

Tags: javascript, function

I was working trying to generate a random number the other day. The assignment is basically that, given an array with names, I was gonna log names on the console at random. I tried to generate a random number that is gonna help accessing the names working as the index of the elements (e.g., array[random_number_as_index]).

My confusion started when storing the method Math.random() in a variable and accessing that same variable, the result was the exact same number over and over. My line of code looks something like this.

`const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10));`

Whereas when part of a function, e.g.,

`function randomNum () {return Math.floor(Math.random()*10));}`

would actually generate a random number every time the function is invoked. My expectation was that, upon accessing the variable, a random number was gonna be generated every single time, which was not the case, and only works if it is within a function.

Comment: "*One would expect that it would generate a random number every time*" - no, why would it? Please explain your thinking.

Comment: If you expect the variable `randomNumber` to _magically_ become a new random value everytime it is read, thats just not how this works.

Comment: `Math.random` gives you a random number. It doesn't give you a object that creates a new random number every time you inspect it.

Comment: `const randomNumber` is a *constant* holding a single number (that was chosen randomly once). It does not change, and it's a number, not a function that can *generate* numbers. When you access a variable, there is no "generating" involved.

Comment: Specifically, "[this] would generate a random number every time" is 100% true: every time you run that _entire line of code_ it will generate a random number and put it in a constant called `randomNumber`.

Comment: You can make it a function: `const randomNumber = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);` - now you can call it again and again: `console.log(randomNumber()); console.log(randomNumber()); console.log(randomNumber()); `

Comment: @Bergi Maybe I phrased it wrong. I expected that, when storing a Math.random() method in a variable, I would generate a random number every time that variable was accessed. Hope this makes sense. I haven't got much experience on JS, so the way it works is not entirely familiar to me.

Comment: @AlexanderMartinez Yeah, but you're not storing the method in the variable. You're calling the method and storing the result (return value, a number) in the variable. This is how most programming languages work.

Comment: @AlexanderMartinez what you have described is more like a macro where text is directly copied to the place it's used before the code runs, but variables doesn't work like macros (there are no macros in js)

Comment: @Bergi Now I get it. Sorry if it was a bit of a pain. I didn't realise all this information you provided. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10));
```

Generates a random number, then assigns that random number to `randomNumber`.

`randomNumber` is a constant variable (meaning its value cannot be changed after the fact).

You're generating one random number, then saving it in a variable.

```js
function randomNum () {return Math.floor(Math.random()*10));}
```

Defines a function that returns a random number when called.

Each invocation of `randomNum` generates a new random number.